# How to use WD My Book Live share as Raspberry PI owncloud server data directory?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, nas, owncloud

I have installed owncloud based on MySQL on a raspberry pi. On my My Book Live NAS I created a new share called owncloud. On my PI I added the following line to /etc/fstab

```
//nas001.local/Owncloud /mnt/shares/nas001/owncloud cifs    username=<user>,password=<pwd>  0   0
```

The share is accessible on /mnt/shares/nas001/owncloud

When I try to finish the owncloud setup I am getting the error message:

```
Can't create or write into the data directory /mnt/shares/nas001/owncloud
```

When I enter the following command I am getting no error message and the content of the directory will be displayed.

```
sudo -u www-data ls -lisa /mnt/shares/nas001/owncloud
```

The owncloud share looks like this

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Feb 14 07:34 owncloud
```

Tried the following

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /mnt/shares/nas001/owncloud
chmod -R 0777 /mnt/shares/nas001/owncloud
```

Nothing changed.

Is there a way to use a My Book Live share as data directory for a Rasperry PI owncloud server?

Comment: Don't understand the -X....

Comment: It is definitely possible, yes. I did the same on my Pi.

Comment: Did you get it to run with the default directory? How do the permissions for the folder look like after you ran `chmod`? The permissions have to be `lrwxrwxrwx`, not `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: With the default directory it is working. After chown and chmod the permissions are drwxr-xr-x!

Comment: I don't have my computer with me so this is a bit uphill. But doing chmod -R 777 /directory, should give permissions rwxrwxrwx. Disregard the "l" in the beginning of my last post, it should be "d" when it is directory. What does ls -l /mnt/shares/ output?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 14 08:52 nas001
I think the problem is that after mounting the NAS share to the directory /mnt/.../owncloud the ownership changes back to root and the permission will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the wrong /etc/fstab entry.

Here is the correct one:

```
//nas001.local/oc /mnt/shares/nas001/owncloud cifs username=<user>,password=<pwd>,uid=33,gid=33,rw,suid,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix 0 0
```